# Passing variable to base html template when url changes

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to pass variable through jinja2 to base html template. If requesting python function test happens by URl - then everything is working okay. But I do need to request pyton function send_user_login_status each time when URL is changed. In this case it does not work. How can I achieve python function send_user_login_status executes every time when user changes URL and passing variable through jinja2 to .html file.

I am using flask.

base.html

```
<li class="{{ login_status_class }}"> {{ login_status }}</li>
```

test.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Python function is working by URL correctly

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_api():
    login_status_class = 'login'
    login_status = u'Enter'
    return render_template("base.html",
                                login_status=login_status,
                                login_status_class=login_status_class)
```

Python function has to work each time when URL changes

```
def send_user_login_status():
    login_status_class = 'login'
    login_status = u'Enter'
    return render_template("base.html",
                           login_status=login_status,
                           login_status_class=login_status_class)
```

**EDIT 1**
For example, I'm trying to call a function send_user_login_status when user goes to the home page. But nothing happens.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    send_user_login_status()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [Flask Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to manage your sessions?

Comment: There are no problems with users' loginisation or validating. But there is a problem that I describe in the question.